# Get attribute name of class attribute

Tags: python, python-3.5, python-descriptors

Here are two discrete objects:

```
class Field(object):
    pass

class MyClass(object):
    firstname = Field()
    lastname = Field()
    email = Field()
```

For any `Field` object, is there inherently a way for that object to be aware of the attribute name that `MyClass` assigned it?

I know I could pass parameters to the `Field` object, like `email = Field(name='email')`, but that would be messy and tedious in my actual case so I'm just wondering if there's a non-manual way of doing the same thing.

Thanks!

Comment: There sort of is a way, but before I write up the answer, I want to make sure you're not making the mistake of thinking those are instance attributes. Those are supposed to be on the _class_, not the instance?

Comment: They are supposed to be class-level attributes, yes, not instance attributes. I realize my example lends itself better to the latter case. Apologies if my use of terminology is incorrect, I'm trusting you understand what I'm getting at.

Comment: Related: [How do I create a variable number of variables?](//stackoverflow.com/q/1373164) (tl;dr: It's quite likely that you're doing something wrong. Maybe you should store those instances in a dict instead?)

Comment: @Aran-Fey I'm not actually looking to create a variable number of variables; the example implies that but it's just an abstraction. 'timmy, jeff and bobby' are the only attributes that will ever exist in this scenario; they could just as easily be "firstname, lastname and email".

Comment: @Aran-Fey  I disagree.  This is standard practice for fields in ORMs, and has use-cases in several other types of frameworks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can make the `Field` class a [descriptor](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors), and then use [`__set_name__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__set_name__) method to bind the name.  No special handling is needed in `MyClass`.

> `object.__set_name__(self, owner, name)`
>   Called at the time the owning class owner is created. The descriptor has been assigned to name.

This method is [available in Python 3.6+](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0487/).

```
>>> class Field:
...     def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
...         print('__set_name__ was called!')
...         print(f'self: {self!r}')  # this is the Field instance (descriptor)
...         print(f'owner: {owner!r}')  # this is the owning class (e.g. MyClass) 
...         print(f'name: {name!r}')  # the name the descriptor was bound to
... 
>>> class MyClass:
...     potato = Field()
... 
__set_name__ was called!
self: <__main__.Field object at 0xcafef00d>
owner: <class '__main__.MyClass'>
name: 'potato'
```

Comment: Oooo this is new. I didn't realize this was added in 3.6

Comment: Yep.  Before PEP 487, people (e.g. Django) were already doing the same thing with metaclasses / introspection hacks.

Comment: +1 Thanks, looks promising and I appreciate the trouble you went to with the example. 3.6 is a bit bleeding edge (I should have specified version) but I'll accept this and upgrade if no universal answers come along.

Comment: @Ivan I suggest upgrading to 3.6 for the new `dict` implementation alone. They maintain insertion order and are significantly more compact, especially for small dicts (which tend to litter Python programs since most user defined objects carry one around d for attributes).